Prove that the inner limit of a set sequence is closed
I am reading the book "Set-Valued, Convex, and Nonsmooth Analysis in Dynamics and Control: An Introduction" by Goebel (https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1.9781611977981).
I am confused by one exercise (if you have the book, it's exercise 2.3).
Given the following definition:

Let $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
The inner limit of the sequence $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$, denoted $\lim \inf_{i \rightarrow \infty} C_i$, is the set of all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for which, for all large enough $i$, there exist points $x_i \in C_i$ such that $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} x_i = x$

prove that $\lim \inf_{i \rightarrow \infty} C_i$ is closed.
What I tried
Let me call $C := \lim \inf_{i \rightarrow \infty} C_i$ for brevity.
I am trying to prove the claim by showing that $\bar C := \mathbb{R}^n \setminus C$ is open.
To this end, take some $\bar x \in \bar C$: I want to show that we can always select a neighborhood of $\bar x$ which is contained in $\bar C$.
Since $\bar x$ is not a limit point, for any sequence $\{x_{k_i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, $\exists \varepsilon_k > 0$ such that $|x_{k_i} - \bar x| > \varepsilon_k$ infinitely often.
Now, if I could prove that $\varepsilon := \inf_k \varepsilon_k > 0$, the $\varepsilon$-ball centered in $\bar x$ would be what I am looking for, but I have no idea on a way to show this.
Am I on the right path, or is this a completely incorrect approach?
Note:
I am aware of the fact that there are other definitions of the inner limit of a set sequence, but I would like to use this one because it is in the book!
Or at least, if there is an equivalent definition that makes the proof easier, could you let me know how you can pass from that to the one I gave?

I'd proceed by contradiction - suppose $\bar{x}$ is not the center of a ball contained $\bar{C}$. Then there must be a sequence in $C$ approaching $\bar{x}$. Use this sequence to prove $\bar{x} \in C$.

Let $(x^n)$ be a sequence in $C$ converging to $x$. We can assume that $\|x-x^n\|<1/n$. For each $n$, there is a corresponding sequence $(x^n_i)$ converging to $x^n$. Let $N_n$ be such that $\|x^n-x_i^n\|<1/n$ for $i\geq N_n$.
Construct a sequence whose first $N_1\vee N_2$ terms are as in $(x^1_i)$, whose next $N_2\vee N_3$ terms are as in $(x^2_i)$, and so on. By construction (and the triangle inequality), the sequence goes first within a distance of $1/1+1/1$ to $x$, then stays within a distance of $1/2+1/2$ of $x$, then a distance of $1/3+1/3$ of $x$, and so on. So this sequence converges to $x$.

Thank you! I had the feeling I should costruct a sequence "piece by piece" but I couldn't figure out the details.
Just one last question: we can assume that $| x - x^n | < 1/n$ because $x$, being the limit point of a sequence of points in $C$, is in the closure of $C$, correct?

@rbertollo Yes. And one can always take a subsequence that converges faster there; the lies-in-$C_i$-requirement does not restrict this sequence.
